# Github custom pull request template

Tags: github, githooks, github-app

Currently, Github supports a pull request template present in the default branch([Link](https://help.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/creating-a-pull-request-template-for-your-repository)). In our team, we want to configure pull request template based on the folder or file modified.

Example configuration we want to support:

```
documentation/ : DOCUMENTATION_TEMPLATE.md
src/**/*.h     : INTERFACE_TEMPLATE.md
src/**/*.cpp   : IMPLEMENTATION_TEMPLATE.md
.config/       : CONFIGURATION_TEMPLATE.md
```

From the Github [documentation](https://help.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/creating-a-pull-request-template-for-your-repository) for Pull requests templates, this seems to be not possible. Can this be achieved either by using Github Webhooks or Github apps?

Comment: It's frustrating that this is still not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted Github and they informed that currently this is not possible. So we ended building a Github App